# javaw.exe consumes memory on starting STS

Tags: memory-leaks, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, javaw

At first I thought my program had memory leaks.  But I terminated all java processes and restarted Spring Tools Suite.  I kept an eye on the task manager.  In just a few minutes, javaw.exe had grown to 2,000,000 K Memory.  The memory keeps going up, without issuing commands in STS.  STS has literally ONLY been opened.  I have no tabs open in it.  The error log doesn't show any memory related errors.  Upon closing STS javaw.exe DOES disappear from task manager and opening STS restarts the process over again around 150,000K, quickly jumping to 600,000K, then slowly growing and growing until it has consumed all my memory.

Any thoughts what might be causing this? I'm running a full system scan now just in case I've been compromised.

--edit--

This problem started around 10 AM Eastern and mysteriously went away at noon, when the security scan completed.  No items were detected by the scan to lend an explanation to either the problem or its mysterious resolution.  As of now javaw.exe is hovering at or around 700,000K.  Very strange!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a 2 hour bug!  Be thankful it is gone but be sure to document it thoroughly if it occurs again.  Sounds like a rough 2 hours you went through.

That is not completely unusual unfortunately. Because Eclipse is made up of a bunch of plug-ins some times a plug-in can go wild and start consuming memory and/or CPU. Using VisualVM (http://visualvm.java.net/) you can determine what is causing Eclipse to freak out. Depending on what it is, you might be able to disable that functionality. Because it could be so many different plug-ins it doesn’t surprise me you could not find any answers googling or looking here at StackOverflow.